# How to use a dynamic ResourceDictionary Source in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to use a dynamic ResourceDictionary Source in Silverlight? My app has one "Styles.xaml" with a lot of style definitions and references a "Colors.xaml" where a couple of brushes are defined:

Styles.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Project;component/Colors.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="MyLayoutTemplate">
    <Button Background="ButtonBackgroundBrush">Button Title</Button>
  </DataTemplate>
  <!-- A lot of other definitions -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Colors.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So basically the Styles.xaml defines the layout and Colors.xaml defines the colors (duh). My App.xaml ONLY references this Styles.xaml.

What I need is a way to do not use this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Project;component/Colors.xaml" />
```

And "point" (or bind) this Source property to a static class where this will be defined dynamically. Something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="{Binding Settings.ThemeUri}" />
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can really achieve this in XAML only, but it is simple to create the dictionaries in code.

```
ResourceDictionary styleDictionary = new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = new Uri("/Project;component/Styles.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
};
ResourceDictionary colorDictionary = new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = new Uri("/Project;component/Colors.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
};

styleDictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(colorDictionary);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(styleDictionary);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. Look the Styles.xaml references Colors.xaml inside of it.

Comment: I think that's just because I have the URI's mixed up in the example. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks again but it still doesn't work. I want be able to choose at runtime the color scheme picking a xaml other than Colors.xaml. The problem is the Styles.xaml has this hard reference to Colors.xaml.

Comment: The resource dictionaries should be defined entirely in code, that way you can set the URI according to your custom logic - the hard coded URI's in my sample are only an example.